# Strange Scala compiler warning

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code in Scala Play Framework:

```
  case class Step(name: String, f: Unit) {
    def run = {() => f}
  }
```

The compiler gives me a strange warning about

```
comparing values of type Unit and Unit using '==' will always yield true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because case classes define an `==` method for you, which compares each of the fields in the case class. So `Step("a", println("1")) == Step("a", println("2"))` is true even thought the `Unit` functions aren't the same.

Comment: Ok, understood, case classes create the apply and unapply method automagically, now I remember. But how should I write this? Or should I just give up on case class and switch to a simple class with class parameters?

Comment: Companion object with an apply method? How does it sound?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do with it. You could override the equals method yourself with `override def equals(x: Any) = x match { case Step(a, b) => a == name case _ => false }`, which will get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly improbably you really need `f: Unit`. After all, `Unit` has only one value: `()`.

I think you might be thinking of doing this:

```
Step("Debugging", println("here"))
```

Which, indeed, respects all types, but will *NOT* print "here" when calling `run`, or applying `run`'s return value. Instead, it will print "here" when you initialize `Step`, and then pass the return value, `()`, to `f`. At the point you call `run`, it will do nothing.

Perhaps you wanted this instead:

```
case class Step(name: String, f: => Unit) {
  def run = {() => f}
}
```

Or even:

```
case class Step(name: String, f: => Unit) {
  def run = f
}
```